# How to fix error in AVAudioPlayer init using swift

Tags: swift, xcode6.1

This is my code and the sound is being played, but after I updated to xcode 6.1 I get this error

**Extra argument 'contentsOfURL' in call**

```
var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound", ofType: "aiff")!)
//println(alertSound);

// Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

var error:NSError?;
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error); // the error
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay();
```

How I can fix the error and xcode to stop showing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
```

The problem is that `alertSound` is now an Optional, because `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` can return nil. You need to unwrap it:

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound!, error: &error)
```

That will allow your code to compile. It is probably better, however, to check explicitly whether `alertSound` is nil before you do that! If it *is* nil, unwrapping it directly will cause a crash.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the pathForResource for URLForResource

Like this :

```
var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sound", ofType: "aiff")!)
```

contentsOfURL need a NSURL not a String.

Comment: He is calling `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)`. It takes a path string, not a URL. It _makes_ a URL, but it _takes_ a path string.